# Parsing the Skills Section in a Resume in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to parse the skills section of a resume in python. I found a library by Mr. Omkar Pathak called pyresparser and I was able to extract a PDF resume's contents into a resume.txt file.

However, I was wondering how I can go about only extracting the skills section from the resume into a list and then writing that list possibly into a query.txt file.

I'm reading the contents of the resume.txt into a list and then comparing that to a list called skills which stores the extracted contents from a skill.cv file. Currently, the skills list is empty and I was wondering how I can go about storing the skills into that list? Is this the correct approach? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
import string
import csv
import re
import sys
import importlib
import os
import spacy
from pyresparser import ResumeParser
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from spacy.matcher import matcher
import multiprocessing as mp

def main():
    data = ResumeParser("C:/Users/infinitel88p/Downloads/resume.pdf").get_extracted_data()
    print(data)

    # Added encoding utf-8 to prevent unicode error
    with open("C:/Users/infinitel88p/Downloads/resume.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as rf:
        rf.truncate()
        rf.write(str(data))

    print("Resume results are getting printed into resume.txt.")

    # Extracting skills
    resume_list = []
    skill_list = []

    data = pd.read_csv("skills.csv")
    skills = list(data.columns.values)

    resume_file = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/resume.txt"
    with open(resume_file, 'r',  encoding='utf-8') as f: 
        for line in f: 
            resume_list.append(line.strip())
            for token  in resume_list:
                if token.lower() in skills:
                    skill_list.append(token)
    print(skill_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: ok well few things I notice, one you are opening the files at "/resume.txt" which would suggest that is in the root folder of your hard drive, then reading it looking at the same folder as your python file which is weird and inconsistent.  Also you are reading the "skills.csv" every line in the resume file which seems like an indentation issue there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment on the "skills.csv" portion of the code! I've edited my post to reflect this change. However, I was wondering what you  mean by, "reading it looking at the same folder as your python file". I'm fairly new to python so just to clarify my code above, I am attempting to read the extracted resume contents in "resume.txt" into my resume_list. Then, I'm comparing the tokens from resume_list with skills from "skills.csv". The skills that match "skills.csv" are then stored into the skill_list.

Comment: a path starting with `/` is absolute so `open("/resume.txt", "w")` will try to create a file right at the root of your file system, then later you do ` os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/resume.txt"` which is grabbing the current folder and grabbing a `resume.txt` in that folder. I would expect that to throw an error saying that "resume.txt" doesn't exist because you are loading from a different place, unless your python script is also at the root directory of your file system in which case the `os.path.dirname(__file__)` will be an empty string and that doesn't add anything but confusion for me.

Comment: Last thing is in general add print statements for various variables in your code and find where the code is going wrong. Particularly you say you are going through each "token" in the resume but your loop looks like you are going through each **line** in the file, so maybe your `token` variable is several words and you want to be splitting that up more?

Comment: Okay, I see the confusion I may have accidentally caused you so I've once again edited the file paths. And I definitely will try splitting the token more so thank you again!

Comment: Could you bring your resume.pdf here?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way ( but not an efficient way ) to do:

Have a set of all possible relevant skills in a text file. For the words in skills sections of the resume or for all the words in resume, take each words and check whether it matches with any of the word from the text file. If a word matched, then that skill is present in resume. This way, you could identify a set of skills present in the resume.

For further addition or better identification, you can use naive-bayes classification or uni-gram probabilities to extract more relevant skills.